# Representing elements in homology of a surface by embedded curves

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Given a closed orientable surface $\Sigma$ is there an algebraic description of the elements of $H_1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z})$ that can be represented by a (connected) simple closed curve?

Comment: Can you find a $\Sigma$ and a class in homology which is not represented by such a curve ? For example, I believe that on a torus any homology class is represented as a connected simple closed curve. Since general surface are connected sum of torus this is probably not complicated to generalize.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that for a manifold $M$ of dimension $\leq 6$, any homology class can be represented by a submanifold (from hearsay). I don't know a proof.

Comment: @N.H. This is not true. Try $(2,2)$.

Comment: @Danu: Correct, but you lose connectivity. And I think it's $d \leq 9$.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMiller. You always know what's going on.

Comment: I think this should be equivalent to the demand that the homology class is primitive (not a multiple of another homology class). On the other hand I think trying to understand which elements of the fundamental group can be represented by embedded loops is hard.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yes, this is equivalent to primitivity. The key is that the homomorphism $Mod(S)\to Sp(2n,Z)$ is surjective, where $n$ is the genus of $S$ and $Mod$ is the mapping class group. The problem then reduces to "linear algebra": $Sp(2n,Z)$ acts transitively on the set of primitive elements of $Z^{2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed:

Theorem. A nonzero element $c\in H_1(\Sigma)$ can be represented by a simple loop if and only if $c$ is primitive, i.e. is **not** of the form $nc'$ where $n$ is an integer $\ne \pm 1$ and $c'\in H_1(\Sigma)$.

For a proof see [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SimpleClosedCurves.pdf), or references below:

M. D. Meyerson, Representing homology classes of closed orientable surfaces, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 61 (1976), no. 1, 181–182 (1977).

J. A. Schafer, Representing homology classes on surfaces, Canad. Math. Bull. 19 (1976), no. 3, 373–374.

W. H. Meeks, III and J. Patrusky, Representing homology classes by embedded circles on a compact surface, Illinois J. Math. 22 (1978), no. 2, 262–269.